# What exactly is the description field when uploading an image?

Tags: images, html

This is a really basic question and I am slightly embarrassed I do not know, but what exact purpose does the description field serve, when uploading an image with Wordpress?

Typically when uploading an image I include a title (maybe) and some alt text. I always thought alt text was to help people with disabilities, so I try to always include it; I usually copy the alt text to the description (which I think would be bad practice), but I can't seem to 'see' the description text anywhere (whilst viewing source). Is it the same as `longdesc`?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click through to an attachment page-- `?attachment_id=123`-- the Description works something like the post body of a normal post (which is basically what it is if you look at the database), or like a long format caption. Of course, I am sure themes can alter that.

I am not sure where else, if anywhere else, the description shows up by default. A theme or a plugin could use the information for other purposes.

Comment: So, it is Wordpress specific, not some html `img` tag I missed. Thanks so much!